# The usage of "at intervals"

Tags: translation, adverbial-phrases

> The ponds are linked with each by waterfalls at intervals from higher terraces to the lower ones.

The sentence is a translation from Chinese to English describing a huge pond formed by several waterfalls; how does it sound? Is it idiomatic?

Say, the usage of at intervals, I can totally understand it because I've seen the original Chinese text, but does it sound natural to native's ears? Like the way it describes how the ponds are linked.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what "at intervals" is supposed to mean in the original text? Does it refer, for example, to various positions along the edges of a pond, or to vertical spacing in some way?

Comment: I suspect (from a similar garden arrangement in which each pond drained via a waterfall into a lower pond) that you need to write: **The ponds are linked with one another by waterfalls at intervals from higher terraces to the lower ones**. (**each other** is also possible. I doubt that you need the phrase **at intervals**. The meaning is quite clear without it.)

Comment: @Ronald Sole you may be right, it can be a translating problem, since the original text contains a word that means "interval," thus it is translated in this way, thanks for pointing out by the way.

Comment: In the arrangement I came across, each pond drained via a single spout into a lower pond. If, however, in the arrangement you are describing, each pond drained via more than one waterfall into lower ponds, then **at intervals** would make sense. But it might need more clarity, as in:  **The ponds (each pond?) drained via (several) waterfalls set at intervals into ponds on lower terraces.**